# Extracting integers from a string - including negative integers

Tags: python, regex, list, integer

I have been trying to extract integers found in randomly generated strings of this type of structure;

```
string1 = "3x-2-44"
```

I have successfully managed to fill a list with the integers found in the string;

```
L1 = (re.findall(r'\d+', string1))
```

'L1' would hold a useful list of all the integers but does not show if the number is negative, for example for 'string1' L1 would hold

```
[3,2,44]
```

rather than something like:

```
[3,-2,-44]
```

How would it be possible to also retrieve the integer's previous character to determine whether its positive or negative?

Comment: `r'\d+'` => `r'-?\d+'`

Comment: Can there be float numbers that you'd want to avoid matching?

Answer (score 2):

Your `regex` should be like:

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = "3x-2-44"

#                v for matching zero or one occurrence of `-` in string  
>>> re.findall('-?\d+', string1)
['3', '-2', '-44']
```

For converting the extracted number strings to `int`, you may use `map` as:

```
>>> list(map(int, re.findall('-?\d+', string1)))
[3, -2, -44]
```